# RegExp how to get data from those brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a string like `[url.com](url)` . I need to replace data from those brackets and pull it into link like `<a href="url.com">url</a>`
Could someone help me to deal with it?

Comment: Share some sample input and their expected outputs along with your attempt.

Comment: 'Some text with (url.com)[url] need to be changed'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `match` with regex `/(?<=(\[|\())([^\])]+)/g`

```
var matches = "[url.com](url)".match(/(?<=(\[|\())([^\])]+)/g) ; //["url.com", "url"]
```

Now use `matches` to form *anchor tag* as

```
var aHTML = "";
if (matches && matches.length == 2)
{
   aHTML = '<a href="' + matches[0] + '">' + matches[0] + '</a>'
}
```

**Edit**

If you have a string having this format and you want to replace inline then

```
var getLink = (str) => {
  var matches = str.match(/(?<=(\[|\())([^\])]+)/g);

  var aHTML = "";
  if (matches && matches.length == 2) {
    aHTML = '<a href="' + matches[0] + '">' + matches[0] + '</a>'
  }
  return aHTML;
};

var replaceInline = (str) => {
   return str.replace( /\[[^\]]+\]\([^)]+\)/g, r => getLink(r) );
};
```

**Demo**

```js
var getLink = (str) => {
  var matches = str.match(/(?<=(\[|\())([^\])]+)/g);

  var aHTML = "";
  if (matches && matches.length == 2) {
    aHTML = '<a href="' + matches[0] + '">' + matches[0] + '</a>'
  }
  return aHTML;
};

var replaceInline = (str) => {
   return str.replace( /\[[^\]]+\]\([^)]+\)/g, r => getLink(r) );
};

var sample = "Here is a link [url.com](url) inline";
console.log( replaceInline(sample) );
```

Comment: And how could I replace this thing in case of string?
'My string with [url.com](url) '

Comment: Didn't get you. What do you mean by *replace this thing in case of string* ?

Comment: if I will have string 'My string with [url.com](url) ', so I need to replace [url.com](url) by <a href="url.com">url</a>